# R equivalent of update query with inner join and conditions

Tags: r

I infrequently use Access to update one table with another table using an inner join and some selection conditions and am trying to find a method to do this sort of operation in R.

```
# Example data to be updated
ID <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C')
Fr <- c(0,1.5,3,0,1.5,4.5,0,3,6)
To <- c(1.5,3,6,1.5,4.5,9,3,6,9)

dfA <- data.frame(ID,Fr,To)
dfA$Vl <- NA
```

I wish to update dfA$Vl using the Vl field ina second data frame as below

```
# Example data to do the updating
ID <- c('A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C')
Fr <- c(0,3,0,1,3,0,4,7)
To <- c(3,6,1,3,9,4,7,9)
Vl <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

dfB <- data.frame(ID,Fr,To,Vl)
```

The following is the Access SQL syntax I would use for this type of update

```
UPDATE DfA INNER JOIN DfB ON DfA.ID = DfB.ID SET DfA.Vl = [DfB].[Vl]
WHERE (((DfA.Fr)<=[DfB].[To]) AND ((DfA.To)>[DfB].[Fr]));
```

This reports that 14 rows are being updated (even through there are only 9 in dfA) as some of the rows will meet the selection conditions more than once and are applied sequentially. I'm not concerned about this inconsistency as the result is sufficient for the intended purpose -- however, it would be best to match the longest overlapping(To-Fr) from DfB to the (To-Fr) of DfA to be more precise - bonus points for that solution)

The result I end up with from Access is as follows

```
# Result
ID <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C')
Fr <- c(0,1.5,3,0,1.5,4.5,0,3,6)
To <- c(1.5,3,6,1.5,4.5,9,3,6,9)
Vl <- c(1,1,2,4,5,5,6,7,8)

dfC <- data.frame(ID,Fr,To,Vl)
```

So the question is the best R way to addressing this operation or alternatively (or additionally) how to reproduce the Access SQL in the R sql packages? Also (for extra credit) how to make sure the majority To-Fr overlap is the number updated not necessary the last update operation?

Comment: Do you want the changes reflected in `dfA` or in a separate data frame `dfC`

Comment: For your main question see https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881. Here some starter `sqldf::sqldf("select A.ID ,B.ID As IDB,A.Fr,B.Fr As FrB,A.Too,B.Too As TooB, B.Vl from dfA A inner join dfB B on A.ID = B.ID AND A.Fr <= B.Too AND A.Too > B.Fr ")` change `To` to `Too`, `sqldf` doesn't like `To`

Comment: Interestingly this gives me all 14 results  - which works for me as I can just select the first or last depending on the day

Comment: To remove the first find the duplicates with x <- x <- which(duplicated(paste0(tst$ID,tst$Fr,tst$Too)) == TRUE) then use this to subset the result of the sql query using something like  dfC <- dfC[- x,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfA); setDT(dfB); setDT(dfC); 
dfA[, rn:=.I]

#non equi join like your ACCESS sql
dfB[dfA, on=.(ID, To>=Fr, Fr<To), .(rn, i.ID, i.Fr, i.To, x.Vl, x.Fr, x.To)][,
    #calculate overlapping range
    rng := pmin(x.To, i.To) - pmax(x.Fr, i.Fr)][,
        #find the rows with max overlapping range and in case of dupes, choose the first row
        first(.SD[rng==max(rng), .(ID=i.ID, Fr=i.Fr, To=i.To, Vl=x.Vl)]), by=.(rn)]
```

output:

```
   rn ID  Fr  To Vl
1:  1  A 0.0 1.5  1
2:  2  A 1.5 3.0  1
3:  3  A 3.0 6.0  2
4:  4  B 0.0 1.5  3  #diff from dfC as Vl=3 has a bigger overlap
5:  5  B 1.5 4.5  4  #diff from dfC. both overlaps by 1.5 so either 4/5 works 
6:  6  B 4.5 9.0  5
7:  7  C 0.0 3.0  6
8:  8  C 3.0 6.0  7
9:  9  C 6.0 9.0  8
```

Comment: Rohit - looking for the changes to be sent to the separate data frame dfC but no reason why updating dfA would not be an acceptable solution

Comment: chinsoon12 -  nice~! Thank you